# How to find the column causes the error on Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-data-factory

> {
>       "errorCode": "2200",
>       "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type decimal of the specified target column.. Failed to convert
>   parameter value from a String to a
>   Decimal.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type decimal of the specified target
>   column.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Failed
>   to convert parameter value from a String to a
>   Decimal.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input
>   string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'",
>       "failureType": "UserError",
>       "target": "Copy Data1" }

Can anyone please let me know the main cause of this error? I am trying to migrate the data from Web API to the Azure SQL database.
I need to know what specific column causes the error.

Comment: Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear:

> column.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy Data1" }

This error is caused by your input dataset.

Please check your source dataset from Web API, during the Copy Active Mapping settings, find which column(String) is mapping to decimal column. Then you can find the error data from your source dataset.

[image]

The data from your source dataset is not a 'decimal' format String which caused the error.

Hope this helps.